# Jekyll paginator killed post.excerpt

Tags: pagination, jekyll

I have got a bizarre behaviour using paginator on a Jekyll generated website.
I used to create the list of the last 3 posts as

```
<ul class="post-list">
    {% for post in site.posts limit:3 %}
      <li>
        <span class="post-meta">{{ post.date | date: "%b %-d, %Y" }}</span>

        <h2>
          <a class="post-link" href="{{ post.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
        </h2>
        <p>{{ post.excerpt }}</p>
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

As soon as I activated the paginator in Jekyll and cycled pages as

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
<div class="post-preview">
    <a href="{{ post.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}">
        <h2 class="post-title">{{ post.title }}</h2>
        {% if post.subtitle %}
        <h3 class="post-subtitle">
            {{ post.subtitle }}
        </h3>
        <p>{{ post.excerpt }}</p>
        {% endif %}
    </a>
    <p class="post-meta">Posted by {% if post.author %}{{ post.author }}{% else %}{{ site.title }}{% endif %} on {{ post.date | date: "%B %-d, %Y" }}</p>
</div>
<hr>
{% endfor %}
```

`post.excerpt` becomes empty. I tried both with the standard behaviour and with the  trick.

Build Settings in _config.yml are as such:

```
# Build settings
gems: [jekyll-sitemap]
markdown: kramdown
highlighter: rouge
permalink: pretty
paginate: 5
paginate_path: "/archives/page/:num"
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've put `{{ post.excerpt }}` expression in a conditional statement.

```
{% if post.subtitle %}
  <h3 class="post-subtitle">{{ post.subtitle }}</h3>
  <p>{{ post.excerpt }}</p>
{% endif %}
```

So, no subtitle, no excerpt !

This is better :

```
{% if post.subtitle %}
  <h3 class="post-subtitle">{{ post.subtitle }}</h3>
{% endif %}
<p>{{ post.excerpt }}</p>
```

In order to render paginated posts you must loop in `paginator.posts` [see documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/pagination/#render-the-paginated-posts)